# Classes have changed completely to XML tags with errors

Tags: java, android, gradle, build

I was working on an android app normally and then when opening the project today i found that all the project contain errors after build, most of java classes -specially activities - have changed to some type of XML that i don't understand. When opening these classes this is what is written instead of complete java files:

```
 <component name="libraryTable">
  <library name="Gradle: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0@jar">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.4.0/fc4aa382632bfaa7be7b41579efba41d5a71ecf3/retrofit-2.4.0.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit2/retrofit/2.4.0/451207353948708405a08287e2a315c3f23553fe/retrofit-2.4.0-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</component>
```

I've checked version control and it turns out that no files where changed to cause this error.

also when i try to run the app an error occurs that no launcher activity found for the project. What could be the cause of this problem? I tried removing all gradle and reinstalling it again as well as reinstalling android studio.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your project is deleted that's why it is showing this.
another thing is try closing and reopen the android studio.

Comment: can you elaborate more on how it's deleted? i still have the project in the same directory and can see every file of it.

Comment: if you are seeing every file with code inside which you have created then its is android studio's issue. do one thing go to project folder and copy all files, now create new folder and paste all the files and after that open that newly created project.

Comment: I tried that and It worked. Thank you for your assistance!